# Update field inside nested type in elasticsearch from java

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mapping, elasticsearch-nested

Please find the below mapping, We are trying to updated the domains field inside the domains type.

```
 "mappings":{  
   "candidate":{  
      "_all":{  
         "enabled":false
      },
      "properties":{  
         "domains":{  
            "properties":{  
               "country":{  
                  "type":"short",
                  "include_in_all":false
               },
               "domains":{  
                  "type":"string",
                  "copy_to":[  
                     "domain_exact",
                     "domain_partial"
                  ]
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

And the java code given below,

```
esMgr.updateIndex(indexName, "candidate", domainDetails[2]).setDoc("domains.domains", domainDetails[1])
                                .get();
```

We are getting the below exception,

```
Caused by: MapperParsingException[Field name [domains.domains] cannot contain '.']
```

Can anyone help us on how to fix this issue in java.

Comment: Field names cannot contain the . character in Elasticsearch 2.0.

Comment: @ Stoyan Dekov  How to update domains.domains from java call ?

Answer (score 0):

To update, you can try:

```
UpdateRequestBuilder br = client.prepareUpdate(indexName, "candidate", domainDetails[2]);
br.setDoc("{\"domains\":{ \"domains\": " + domainDetails[1] + "}}".getBytes());
br.execute();
```